# Pasar una funcion de un componente a otro REACT basado en clases

Tags: reactjs

Tengo el siguiente ejemplo, pues quiero pasar esta funcion a otro componente basado también en una clase.
Pero como hago para utilizar ese prop en una clase?

```
class App extends Component {

  sayHi = () => {
    console.log('Hi from APP');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
       
           <ColourShopBuilder  sayHi = {this.sayHi}/> 
       
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

class ColourShopBuilder extends Component {
 
  render() {
    return (
      <Auxilary>
        <Toolbar
         
        />
        <Modal show=
          <OrderSummary
           
          />
        </Modal>
        <Shop>
          <ShopColor
            clicked={() => this.props.sayHi}
          />
        </Shop>
      </Auxilary>
    );
  }
```

He probado a pasarlo asi, pero no funciona, cómo deberia hacerlo?

Edito con el component ShopColor

```
const shopColor = (props) => {
  const colors = props.listColors.map((c, key) => (
    <article
      onClick = {props.clicked}
      className={classes.ShopColor}
      key={key}
      style={{ backgroundColor: c.color }}
    >
      <Price price={c.price} />
      <Cart addToCart={() => props.addToCart(c.color, c.price)} />
    </article>
  ));
  return <Auxilary>{colors}</Auxilary>;
};
```

Comment: Aparentemente está bien, habría q ver tu componente <ShopColor/>

Comment: He editado añadiendo el componente, lo que pasa que clico encima del article pero no me sale el mensaje que debe salir

Comment: Intenta pasandole la función al componente <ShopColor /> directamente sin usar una función anómima <ShopColor clicked={this.props.sayHi}/> y declara tu función sayHi ya sea let, var o const

Comment: Vale era eso, y una pregunta por que en una función anónima no funcionaba?

Comment: Porque tu variable sayHi, es una variable que contiene una función anónima, que muestra algo por consola, luego cuando hacías clicked={() => this.props.sayHi}, estabas creando una función anónima que devolvía otra función anónima, pero nunca se ejecutaba lo que contenía esta última.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí te dejo una explicación mas clara.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes observar "sayHi" a solas, contiene una función anónima que para poder ejecutarse debes llamar a "sayHi" como una función como tal "sayHi()"

Ahora cuando le pasas esa función a través de otra función anónima como hiciste en "clicked={() => this.props.sayHi}" que es similar a lo que hago creando otra variable "say2" en la cual creo una función anónima que me retorna mi anterior variable "sayHi". Entonces cuando ejecuto "say2()" simplemente me devuelve mi variable "sayHi" la cual contiene una función anónima

Comment: Gracias por la explicación